# How to construct a list as (key,value) pairs with PyMySQL and Python?

Tags: python, pymysql

I have the following code:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(...)
try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
       sql = "select cola,colb from ...."
       result = cursor.fetchall()
       How to build a list from the result?
finally:
    connection.close()
```

The query returns data as:

```
cola   colb
-----------
123    abc
124    abd
140    ghf
```

`cola` is the `key`

`colb` is the `value`

I know it should be something like:

```
list = []
for i in range (0, ????): 
     cola_value = result[0][i].get('cola')
     colb_value = result[1][i].get('colb')
     list.append((cola_value, colb_value))
```

I'm wondering what is the correct syntax and if this is the correct approach?
I want to be able to search the list by key and access the value by key.

I'll need 2-3 lists each one with around  900000 (key,value) pairs.
Is it smart to manage it in memory or better to write it to file and process it on disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not try this, but you should be able to use a list comprehension:

```
list = [(r['cola'], r['colb']) for r in result]
```

If you plan to do lookups by key, using a dictionary would be even better:

```
map = {r['cola']: r['colb'] for r in result}
```

Then if you want to find the value corresponding with they key `123`:

```
value = map[123]
```

Regarding whether or not it makes sense to hold 900,000 pairs depends on your hardware resources - there are probably more memory efficient ways to do it, but you might need to install some additional dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify cursorclass in pymysql.connection function, it will give you the list of dictionary as mentioned below:

Below is the function call:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(db='foo', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM bar")
print cursor.fetchall()
```

Below is the output of the cursor:

```
[{u'col2': 'rty', u'col1': 'qwe'}, {u'col2': 'fgh', u'col1': 'asd'}]
```